# Rails - Multiple Select Update all objects of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, jquery-select2

I have a 'country' model in my app with attributes name and status. If a country is activated, its status will be 1. Admin type of user can toggle this so I have given a multiple select dropdown for the same. My problem, how to update all the selected/unselected countries at one hit of submit button ?

My form on settings page for Admin user -

```
<%= simple_form_for @country do |form| %>
      <%= form.collection_select :name, Country.order(:name), :id, :name, {:selected => @selected}, {:multiple => true, :class =>"ui fluid  selection dropdown"}  %>
      <%= form.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Controller -

```
def settings
  @country = Country.new
  @selected = Country.where(status: '1').pluck(:id)
end
```

And the script -

```
<script>
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
});
```

Comment: When you submit the form, what do the parameters look like in the server logs? It should look like: `Started PATCH ... Processing by SomeController#action as HTML ... Parameters: {...}`. Please update your answer to show this information.

Comment: `@country = Country.new` What is this for? As far as I can tell, it serves no purpose. `@selected = Country.where(status: '1')` -- That's not reading the submitted form data at all. When you click "submit", the selected countries should be present in the `params`.

Comment: You should be able to do *something along the lines of* `Country.where(id: params[:countries][:ids]).update_all(status: :active)` --- but I cannot give an exact answer without knowing more details - like, what is `params`, and how do you propose to update the model? (Also, can updating the status fail - e.g. a validation? If so, how would you expect to handle the failure?)